# How can I make a discord currency system and/or music bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[post edited]

How can I make a discord currency system with python and/or how do I download the FFmpeg thing for the music bot as I don't know what to do after installing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I am assuming you want your commands to work with your `on_message` event. For that, just add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of your event.

Comment: If you want to use multiple files to organize your bot, take a look at the cog system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to bring them to the same python file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@client.command ()
async def repeat (ctx, arg):
        await ctx.send(arg)

@client.event
async def on_message (message):
        message.content = message.content.lower()
        if message.author == client.user:
                return
        if message.content.startswith("$hello"):
                if str(message.author) == "NAME":
                        await message.channel.send ("Hello" + str(message.author) + "!")
                else:
                        await message.channel.send("Hello!!")


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Then it depends on what you mean by "Work toghether". If you need the bot to answer to `$hello` and `$repeat` separately the code is already good.

Comment: When i mean 'Work together' i mean like i can use both $hello and $repeat and they answer when i type them in one after the other. Before i had to run the file individually to get them to work but you put the commands in the same folder so im guessing its going to work.